# Second Big Bang

Tags: universe, big-bang-theory

Just say you are immortal and will live forever. Since the universe is claimed to be unstable, what would happen after it ends? Would all of the universe's mass just fly back into another compressed ball, and explode again? Would you be torn apart and flung across the new universe?

Comment: Perhaps think about what we had to overcome to get to the position where we are today (early Universe) and maybe also read up about the current expansion of the Universe. This might lead you down the path where you can read up on "the Big freeze"...

Comment: The universe is not necessarily unstable, and the Big Bang did not happen at a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As such the answer 'I don't know' is more appropriate than anything else.
But for an answer to give---
Fate of universe depends upon many aspects - but mainly the density of the universe. There is a critical density of the universe which is not enough to produce gravitational effect to stop expansion and nor that weak to keep the universe to expand at an increasing rate. This can be more clearly understood with help of 4-d diagrammatic representation of the expansion(or contraction). When it is critical, the diagram is flat with no net curvature. When the density is less CD(Critical Density), there is a saddle shaped diagram which represents vigorously increasing rate of expansion. When density is greater than CD, there is a contraction.

Now, apart from baryonic matter, mysterious dark matter and dark energy come into effect. All these, at this moment, is making the universe accelerating, as we all know. Till now, expectations are towards forming a 'rip', or violent expansion of universe where even atoms will be torn away in distant future.

Concept of second Big Bang is still far from our views, but quoting Stephen Hawking --- "God not only plays dice but also casts it where no one can see" --- Let nature do what she wants.